# Translation doubts

Tags: translation

大好きなあのコ

This means: The girl I love/I love you

I'm interested in knowing if it absolutely has to refer to a person that's not in front of you.

I also want to know if 大好き (like very much) can mean favourite in this sentence (something like my favourite girl or the girl I love the most).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means neither.

あのコ is not "you" but "that girl", referring to someone who is *not* in front of you. If you said this to your girlfriend in front of you, you would probably make her angry; "Wait, who is あのコ? Who are you talking about!?"

The sentence means "That girl I love." 大好き means "love" or "like very much", but it does not mean "love the most" on its own.

Comment: Um, we don't say 'drive someone angry' in English. We say 'drive someone mad', but it means 狂わせる, not 怒らせる.

Comment: @Nothingatall I also thought I haven't seen it before, but it was listed [here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=drive%20someone%20angry&ref=sa). Thank you, I almost memorized it as a valid phrase :)

Comment: @Mac Please edit your question to include details like these rather than putting them in the comments section.